# Object #<Scope> Error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am calling the following function in my controller:

```
              try
              {
                  alert('it works!');
                  $scope.insert('John', 'Doe');
              }
              catch(err)
              {
                  alert('err=' + err);
              }

 $scope.insert = function(firstname, lastname) {
        var query = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?,?)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [firstname, lastname]).then(function(res) {
            console.log("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
```

When I run it, sometimes it works and adds the data and sometimes I get the following error:

```
err=TypeError: Object #<Scope> has no method 'insert'
```

I have seen this error is quite common but I didn't find an answer that applies to this sample as it actually sometimes the insert works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using expressions to declare functions, `$scope.insert()` is called before it's defined, so you need to move function insert definition before try catch block.

However if you define you insert function as

```
function insert(firstName, lastName) { ... }
```

function `insert` would be defined before try catch block even we don't change its sequence.

Comment: I answered my own question a few seconds before you :) but thanks anyway

Comment: Check my update to know more about function declaration. @carol1287

Answer (score 0):

It seems I just moved  `$scope.insert('John', 'Doe');` after declaring and now i don't get the error anymore :). That was an easy fix!